# IPython NoConsoleScreenBufferError (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, ipython, pycharm

When running any line on the IPython CLI on Windows, most times I am getting a `NoConsoleScreenBufferError` and the console is terminated.

This happens when running IPython from the Windows terminal (`cmd.exe` > `ipython`) or when using the embedded PyCharm terminal (it uses the Windows terminal) which chooses IPython automatically over the regular Python terminal, in installed.

Here is part of the relevant trace:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 119, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 348, in start
    self.shell.mainloop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\interactiveshell.py", line 486, in mainloop
    self.interact()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\interactiveshell.py", line 469, in interact
    code = self.prompt_for_code()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\interactiveshell.py", line 363, in prompt_for_code
    pre_run=self.pre_prompt, reset_current_buffer=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\interface.py", line 392, in run
    self._redraw()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\interface.py", line 351, in _redraw
    self.renderer.render(self, self.layout, is_done=self.is_done)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\renderer.py", line 398, in render
    size = output.get_size()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\terminal\win32_output.py", line 103, in get_size
    info = self.get_win32_screen_buffer_info()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\terminal\win32_output.py", line 150, in get_win32_screen_buffer_info
    raise NoConsoleScreenBufferError
NoConsoleScreenBufferError: No Windows console found. Are you running cmd.exe?

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@scipy.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    %config Application.verbose_crash=True
```

Comment: What's your IPython version? Is it the latest?

Comment: @leovp It is the version 5.3.0.

Comment: Huh, upgrading IPython with `pip install --upgrade ipython` seemed to work. Although the version stays the same. Knock on wood.

Comment: For anyone else stumbling upon this, see latest here: https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/issues/406